# Is my Roland FP-7F keyboard touch sensitive?

Tags: keyboard

My piano teacher asked me if my keyboard can play soft with my left hand and harder with my right. I am not so sure I can do that. Must I buy a piano?

Comment: Simple check is to turn it on, and play a note or two gently, then getting more forceful. If the sound gets louder, it's touch sensitive, but in a different way from an acoustic piano. Ideally, your teacher should try your piano for himself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your teacher wants a touch sensitive piano. This means the volume and timbre change depending on how hard you play the keys.

I have access to a FP-7F, and it's definitely touch sensitive. Whilst a real piano is nice, the FP-7F should be fine for your needs.